# How is attachment access controlled by record level

Tags: security, attachment

By looking at the permission set and profile metadata files, I don't see a place defining the access to contentDocument or ContentVersion so I originally assumed it should be controlled by parent. However, when I use the user I created I can see the parent case record but can't see the attached png file to the case when doing the soql query.

The query to ContentDocument does return a bunch of records, so which means the user does have access to some ContentDocument records but not those ones. So where am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, this is the missing [(ContentDocument)Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) (seriously, I've waited ages to use this pun). Depending on the `ShareType`, the file might not be visible to people who can view the related record. A `ContentDocument` isn't viewable by non-admins until they are also shared. Make sure you have an associated `ContentDocumentLink` and that the `ShareType` is set to `I` (for "Inferred Sharing").

Comment: I tried with the process but I find things to get even more weird. When I paste the file's link and open it from my new user's session, I can actually see the file. But I can't see it when I query ContentDocument or ContentVersion. But the same record can be queried with my admin account.